# jquery: alter css on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I need a jquery code snippet that alters a css value (from min value to max value - both can be declared) when user scrolls a page. According to the scroll position, the CSS value (for example height) of a div should be changed "in realtime".

Let's say the scolling becomes a range between 0 and max. 200px. (When scrolled more then 200px it shouldn't affect the CSS value anymore.)

And the CSS value besomes a range between 300px and 600px.

This is what the jquery routine should do:

```
Scroll=0px: CSS value=300px
Scroll=100px: CSS value=450px
Scroll=200px: CSS value=600px
```

It's probably a very easy snippet. Could somebody maybe help me out. That would be super. Thank you very much! Best regards, Pierre

Comment: Are your scroll values supposed to be distance from the top of the viewport?

Comment: Welcome! Please see [ask], including how to include an [mcve].  As it stands, this question is too broad and requires someone to do a _lot_ of work before they can offer an answer.

Comment: "Are your scroll values supposed to be distance from the top of the viewport?" Yes!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$(window).scroll(function()` to trigger on scroll event and then get the scroll amount for desired div or whatever needed, in this example i used `window`. Then check the scroll amount `if(scroll >= minScroll && scroll < MaxScroll)` and perform desired action

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log(scroll);
  
  if(scroll >= 200 && scroll < 700){
    $(".box").css("background-color", "blue");
  }
  
   else if(scroll >= 700 && scroll < 1300){
    $(".box").css("background-color", "green");
  }
  
   else if(scroll >= 1300 && scroll < 2000){
    $(".box").css("background-color", "purple");
  }
  
   else if(scroll >= 2000 && scroll < 3000){
    $(".box").css("background-color", "orange");
  }
});
```

```css
.box{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 3000px;
  width 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In my case it is crucial that the css value is being changed continuously / linear without fix steps.

Comment: @PierreHansen - case in point to my comment above: if your comment is accurate, then the question as asked is unclear, and needs to be sharpened so folks who are trying to help don't waste their time :)